# `git clone` fails for role in private git repo when running `ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml`

Tags: git, ssh, ansible, gitlab

I have added a `.gitlab-ci.yml` to my private project. One of the steps is to get a role from a private gitlab repo. However this fails with

```
/usr/bin/git clone ssh://git@gitlab.com/papanito/ansible-role-bootstrap.git
papanito.bootstrap failed in directory /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-
local-1036kia7b4eu/tmpjcyiks12 (rc=128)
ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Running the same command `ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml` on my machine runs fine.

I add a private key for the ci user before running the command. So not sure what I still miss.

### `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
variables:
  SITE: "site.yml"
  PLAYBOOKS: "playbooks/*.yml"

stages:
  - verify

before_script:
  - whoami
  - apt-get update -qy #update system
  - mkdir ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo $SSHKEY_GITLAB > ~/.ssh/id_rsa # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys
  - chmod 640 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - apt-get install ansible ansible-lint -qy
  - git submodule update --init
  - ansible --version
  - ansible-lint --version
  - git config -l
  - ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml

ansible-verify:
  stage: verify
  script:
    - ansible-lint -v $SITE
    - ansible-lint -v $PLAYBOOKS
    - ansible-playbook --syntax-check $SITE
    - ansible-playbook --syntax-check $PLAYBOOKS
```

### `requirements.yml`

```
- src: geerlingguy.docker
- src: dev-sec.ssh-hardening
- src: m4rcu5nl.zerotier-one

# own roles
- src: https://git@github.com/papanito/ansible-role-rsyslog.git
  name: papanito.rsyslog
  scm: git
  version: master
- src: git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/papanito/ansible-role-bootstrap.git
  name: papanito.bootstrap
  scm: git
  version: master
```

### Log

```
$ ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
- downloading role 'docker', owned by geerlingguy
- downloading role from https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-docker/archive/2.8.1.tar.gz
- extracting geerlingguy.docker to /root/.ansible/roles/geerlingguy.docker
- geerlingguy.docker (2.8.1) was installed successfully
- downloading role 'ssh-hardening', owned by dev-sec
- downloading role from https://github.com/dev-sec/ansible-ssh-hardening/archive/9.3.0.tar.gz
- extracting dev-sec.ssh-hardening to /root/.ansible/roles/dev-sec.ssh-hardening
- dev-sec.ssh-hardening (9.3.0) was installed successfully
- downloading role 'zerotier-one', owned by m4rcu5nl
- downloading role from https://github.com/m4rcu5nl/ansible-role-zerotier/archive/v1.2.3.tar.gz
- extracting m4rcu5nl.zerotier-one to /root/.ansible/roles/m4rcu5nl.zerotier-one
- m4rcu5nl.zerotier-one (v1.2.3) was installed successfully
- extracting papanito.rsyslog to /root/.ansible/roles/papanito.rsyslog
- papanito.rsyslog (master) was installed successfully
 [WARNING] Ansible is being run in a world writable directory (/builds/papanito/infrastructure), ignoring it as an ansible.cfg source. For more information see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/config.html#cfg-in-world-writable-dir
 [WARNING]: - papanito.bootstrap was NOT installed successfully: - command
/usr/bin/git clone ssh://git@gitlab.com/papanito/ansible-role-bootstrap.git
papanito.bootstrap failed in directory /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-
local-1036kia7b4eu/tmpjcyiks12 (rc=128)
ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: What version of Git is installed on the system on which ansible is running `/usr/bin/git`? Does the user that ansible is using here have a `$HOME/.gitconfig`?

Comment: Good question, I know it uses `gitlab-runner 13.2.0-rc2` so I would have to check which git version it uses.

Comment: You can check the actual authentication from within your job via `ssh git@gitlab.com` which should respond with "Welcome to GitLab, $USERNAME!" if everything is a-ok

Comment: git is version `2.20.1`. `ssh@gitlab.com` fails with `Host key verification failed`

Comment: Mhh would be interesting to know why the downrate of the post...

Comment: *fails with Host key verification failed* then that's what's killing your `git clone` command, too; you can use [`ssh-keyscan`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ssh-keyscan.1.html) or create a `$HOME/.ssh/config` containing [`StrictHostKeyChecking no`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html) depending on your threat model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Running the same command `ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml` on my machine runs fine.

That means you have the right public/private key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` on your machine, and you are executing it locally with your account.

If you copy it in your GitLab step, make sure to check the rights, and possible the passphrase and known_hosts, [as in here](https://gist.github.com/yannhowe/5ab1501156bd84c8ac261e2c17b8e3e0) or in [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/):

```
  # Paste the PRIVATE key into a gitlab variable. Pay attention to the linebreak at the end when pasting
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo "$DEPLOY_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - ssh-keyscan -H 'your.server.hostname' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Thanks `ssh-keyscan -H 'gitlab.com' >> ~/.ssh/known_host` helped. I also figured I don't have to store the file locally, so I use `cat $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add `

Comment: And I probably need to read more careful the docu from gitlab, it's actually quite comprehensive

Comment: If you copy the private key into the target machine you don't need ssh forwarding anymore

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to use more secure ssh forwarding instead of copying the private key into the machine but found that ansible-galaxy doesn't work properly and relays on `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key only

So here is my updated version of @VonC answer:

```yaml
 - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
 - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
 - echo "$DEPLOY_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 - ssh-keyscan -H 'your.server.hostname' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
 - ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

It was removed `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` commands and added a standard check of git authentication for easier monitoring. You only need them if you add several private keys for different git servers.

It might be good to remove the private key on the last deployment step if it is not necessary for operation.

Comment: Thanks for the update, also upvoted the post